# Locust master distributed using 100% of its CPU stops spawning users

Tags: locust

I'm running Locust (2.4.3) master distributed with this command:

```
locust --master -f device_events_locustfile.py --only-summary --csv device --spawn-rate 50 --users 8000 --host http://localhost --expect-workers 1 --headless --logfile locust.log --run-time 3h
```

The 'host' isn't actually used. The task makes about 10 calls to upload a file to a storage bucket using the full URL with a POST request via the HttpUser client.

I'm running locust workers in kubernetes with horizontal pod autoscaling configured to scale up when cpu exceeds 70%.

The workers use google cloud sdks to interact with cloud storage and firestore, so I have this near the top of the file:

```
import grpc.experimental.gevent as grpc_gevent
grpc_gevent.init_gevent()
```

Locust master pegs its cpu at 100% and stops spawning users. I've tried running the master process in kubernetes as well as a VM and I've tried varying the number of workers that connect to the master from very low (5), to very high (200). When  the number of workers is very high, the locust master process is eventually killed by the OS. Nothing is jumping out in the logs.

Here's a sample of the logs when the locust master is using 100% of its cpu and things grind to a halt.

```
[2021-11-03 16:26:14,903] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Sending spawn messages for 920 total users to 13 client(s)
[2021-11-03 16:26:34,462] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Currently spawned users: {"Device": 920} (920 total users)
[2021-11-03 16:26:34,463] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Sending spawn messages for 940 total users to 13 client(s)
[2021-11-03 16:26:48,520] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Currently spawned users: {"Device": 940} (940 total users)
[2021-11-03 16:26:48,521] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Sending spawn messages for 960 total users to 13 client(s)
[2021-11-03 16:27:15,648] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Currently spawned users: {"Device": 960} (960 total users)
[2021-11-03 16:27:15,649] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Sending spawn messages for 980 total users to 13 client(s)
[2021-11-03 16:27:35,438] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Currently spawned users: {"Device": 980} (980 total users)
[2021-11-03 16:27:35,438] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Sending spawn messages for 1000 total users to 13 client(s)
[2021-11-03 16:28:09,687] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-worker-86dbcf7496-g2pqd_892db30fca0e444d95e145c1220db187' reported as ready. Currently 14 clients ready to swarm.
[2021-11-03 16:28:09,687] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-worker-86dbcf7496-x5bbx_c9022680a3bd49edb5293c1c32367ec8' reported as ready. Currently 15 clients ready to swarm.
[2021-11-03 16:28:09,688] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-worker-86dbcf7496-cktmg_3749c0d76dd84627adb2d5e5740c945d' reported as ready. Currently 16 clients ready to swarm.
[2021-11-03 16:28:13,735] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Currently spawned users: {"Device": 1000} (1000 total users)
[2021-11-03 16:28:13,735] locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz/DEBUG/locust.runners: Sending spawn messages for 1000 total users to 16 client(s)
```

Here's the output from kubernetes top running against the namespace its in.

```
locust-master-68c9b8c5ff-sqjgz   1002m        4039Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-4rljg   788m         210Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-5rztw   823m         254Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-64jxk   819m         255Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-6c78p   791m         258Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-7c58h   776m         209Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-8t25h   806m         256Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-9hz6h   824m         253Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-cktmg   833m         151Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-ffphs   791m         208Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-g2pqd   799m         156Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-gf88z   794m         256Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-k54gz   1m           60Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-n5xkb   827m         254Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-q5hxp   782m         255Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-qvhjt   822m         255Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-r76mj   780m         255Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-x5bbx   773m         156Mi
locust-worker-86dbcf7496-zzfx5   1m           60Mi
```

I've only got one user class. I changed it to pull data from an in memory json list thinking the issue may be around using the firebase admin sdk, but that didn't help either.

I only have 1 user class, and I'm not certain I can publicly post some of it. In essence, it uses an on_start to load about 10 files from the local file system and populate a list. It then loops through the list and uses self.client to make a rest call to upload the file to google cloud. So even though there's a single task, it makes around 10ish api calls.

Comment: Are you on latest release? Can you post your master logs and some more from your locustfile? Do you have a large number of different User classes?

Comment: I updated the post with the info you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this. I believe the root issue was each request generated a unique URL. Locust tracks the number of requests per URL out of the box. I'm speculating, but I assume it uses a hash map or something similar and all of the URLs blew up the memory and CPU required to increment the counters. I grouped all of the urls under a single 'name' using:

```
self.client.post(url, data=file, headers=headers, name="bucket")
```

and that solved it.

Comment: That makes sense! We should add a warning for that I think…